# Make internal classes accessible to all external assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

I'm implementing a modding interface for a game written in .net using Harmony. The original game code consists of mostly classes without specific access modifiers, which unfortunately defaults them to `internal` and makes modding kind of a pain. I have access to the original source code, so I can modify it however I want.

I'm aware of Friend Assemblies and the `ignoreaccesschecksto` modifier, but these options don't really lend themselves well to a modding interface.

I believe the correct way to do this is to manually change all the classes to `public`. Is there a better way to do this/is this a bad idea?

Comment: changing to public would be the best way to do this

Comment: Do you really need to make _all_ classes `public`? Why not just the ones that act as natural entry points for modding?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Sorry, I meant all as in all the default access classes. There's just a lot of them. It's a lot easier to automatically change access of every class then to manually pick through thousands of classes and decide which ones make sense to be public.

Comment: Try to search about `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembly.Tests")]`